# java spring boot amqp two listeners with different behaviour

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I'm new to spring amqp and I would like to create two different listeners with different behaviour. The problem is that I don't know the queue names at compile time, so I cannot use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287113/how-to-listen-to-multiple-queues-with-autowired-spring-boot) solution.

The thing I would like to do, is: read (and then remove) the first message from the "sidechannel" queue, it should look like this `{"queues":["queue1","queue2"]}`.

Now read (then remove) the first message from queue1 and queue2. After this, go to step 1, read the first message of the sidechannel

I tried to create 2 SimpleMessageListenerContainers with diferent listeners as you can see on the code below, but it doesn't work as I thought it would.

My code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

final static String queueName = "sidechannel";

@Autowired
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(sidechannelListener());
    return container;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer2() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames("queue1","queue2");
    container.setMessageListener(queueListener());
    return container;
}



@Bean
public MessageListener sidechannelListener() {
    return message -> {
        String msg = new String(message.getBody());
        System.out.println(msg);
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = jsonToMap(msg);
            for (String name : (ArrayList<String>) map.get("queues")) {
                System.out.println("Waiting for " + name + " message");
                rabbitTemplate.receive(name);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    };
}

@Bean
public MessageListener queueListener() {
    return message -> {
        String msg = new String(message.getBody());
        System.out.println("Received message: ");
        System.out.println(msg);
    };
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    rabbitTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(-1);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for side channel message");
        rabbitTemplate.receive(queueName);
    }
//        context.close();
}
}
```

First, for some reason, the message in the sidechannel queue will not remove after being processed.
Second, when I was expecting an output like this:

```
Waiting for side channel message
{"queues":["queue1","queue2"]}
Waiting for queue1 message
Received message:
"message from queue1"
Waiting for queue2 message
"message from queue2"
Waiting for side channel message
```

and that even if I received messages on those different queues, nothing would happen (because of `rabbitTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(-1);`), but somehow it reacts to every message that I receive...

Also, what I don't understand is, that if I first send a message to sidechannel, then to queue1 it goes like:

```
Waiting for side channel message
{"queues":["queue1","queue2"]}
Waiting for queue1 message
Received message:
"message from queue1"
```

and now, if I send another (a second) message to queue1, it prints out the message and then `Waiting for queue2 message`.

So it needs two messages to continue the cycle... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Looks overly complex to me, why aren't you just using configuration? Specify the queue names at startup (if you can put them on an exchange you can also put them in a properties file).

Comment: It might be very complex, as I said, I'm new to spring amqp and I still have trouble understanding it. But since I don't know the queue names at compile time I can't add them to a property file, or am I wrong? Anyway Gary's answer helped me solve the issue, thank you for your reply :)

Comment: You don't need to know them at compile time. I suggest a read of the reference guide. You can provide the properties at the moment of startup, properties can be defined later, you wold only need a fixed property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing paradigms; you have listener containers which are message-driven and you are also using polling (`template.receive()`). In general, the container for queue1, queue2 will have already processed the messages from those queues and this

```
            System.out.println("Waiting for " + name + " message");
            rabbitTemplate.receive(name);
```

will block forever if the timeout is < 0; hence the original message will never be ack'd.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know listener containers are message-driven, that somehow explain it whole and I can solve it, thank you very much!